# regression homework in R

Tags: r, regression

I have a data set labeled bond for different cities:
$y$=bond yield, $x_1$=offer size ($\$$1000 bonds) and $x_2$=term of maturity (100's of months).
 I need to compare coefficients for all models $y=b_0+b_2x_2$, $y=c_0+c_1x_1+c_2x_2$ and $y=d_0+d_1x_1$.

I was able to do the first model but I get errors for the other two. This is the values of the first six cities.

```
> head(bond)
  N0       City X1   X2   Y  
1  1 Birmingham 30 1.81 335 
2  2     Oxnard 10 1.93 365 
3  3    Salinas 30 2.79 315 
4  4    Danbury 15 1.81 325 
5  5  New Haven 15 1.87 283 
6  6    Norwalk 40 2.17 300
```

the linear model2 was  `c <- lm(y ~ X1 + X2, bond)` which yielded

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ X1 + X2, data = bond, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'X1')
```

and the last model was `d <- lm(y ~ X1, bond)` which resulted in

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ X1, data = bond, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'X1')
```

**Question:** I dont understand the error or how to proceed to correct it.

Comment: Have you checked for missing value in $y$, $x_1$, and $x_2$?

Comment: yes, each column has a value in y,x1 and x2

Comment: @mark. This looks like an R question rather than a stats question, and as such would go on stackoverflow with an '[r]' tag.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like the length of y and X1 are different. I bet that's because you should have used Y not y.

The function `ls()` can sometimes help you find extra variables with similar names that you might accidentally use. You can always `rm` any you don't need. Unless you're pretty disciplined about your use of variables, clearing out your workspace each time before starting work is often a good idea.